# What is bytecode transformation?

Tags: jvm, bytecode-manipulation, dagger-hilt, jvm-bytecode

While reading a documentation of [dagger-hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html#hilt-test-dependencies), I came across such a term "bytecode transformation". What is bytecode transformation ?

the complete sentence

> The Hilt Gradle plugin runs a bytecode transformation to make the APIs
> easier to use.

What is the benefit of using bytecode transformation ?

Comment: When you compile Java, javac will emit bytecode (`.class` files). Applying an additional processing step on those files to transform them is called bytecode transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bytecode transformation happens after compilation and before dexing. Its input is bytecode and output is bytecode.

Android tools team has privately announced that the existing bytecode transformation API is going to be deprecated and replaced with new ones. Hopefully they will publish bytecode transformations soon.

Readmore:

- My blogpost for one simpler usecase of bytecode transformation https://chao2zhang.medium.com/debugging-livedata-changes-made-easy-d3aa16b81b41
- Dagger Hilt implementation https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/hilt/android/plugin/src/main/kotlin/dagger/hilt/android/plugin/HiltGradlePlugin.kt